# is edit tangent possible in 3dsmax?

Tags: unity, 3dsmax

[image: normal & tangent]

I have a custom hlsl directx shader,
it takes vertex normals for rim light calculation.
and vertex tangent(it stores unified normals) for edge render(enlarge model & cull front).

I can export one fbx with auto smooth normals, and one fbx with unify normals, combine them in unity, it works but the process is slow. I just wonder if I can do it directly in 3ds max, so 3d artist can preview the result directly in their tools.

I tried storing unify normals data in texture coordinate or vertex color, but the data will be wrong once bone animation is running. So I believe normal + tangent is the only way to go if I want to have rim lighting & edge render together for a animated character model use in Unity3D.

I guess FBX SDK will help, but I have no experience in using it.

I wish someone could tell me a way to store vertex normals data into tangent.
or tell me is it not possible so that I should consider another solution.

thanks you.